# Property added to view model doesn't produce items to a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

My view model class is very simple.

```
class Presenter
{
  public IEnumerable<String> JustFake => new List<String> { "aaa", "bbb" };

  public Presenter() { }
}
```

IN XAML I've added a combo box bound to the property as follows.

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:Presenter/>
</Window.DataContext>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding JustFake}"/>
```

However, although intellisense found *JustFake*, the values don't appear in the combo box. It's empty. I've tried implementing *INotify...* etc. but nothing gave me any difference. I can't really tell what I can be missing. Should I inherit something else (I saw a [blog where they mentioned](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx) *BindableBase*, whatever that class might be)? Should I introduce the *Presenter* in another way?

Comment: Perhaps you post your real Presenter class declaration here. Nobody understands that `JustFake => new List<String>` syntax. In case it should be read as `JustFake = new List<String> { ... }` then it's not a property, but just a field. WPF data binding works with public properties only.

Comment: @Clemens It actually **is** the class. I removed everything and restarted the view model from scratch. As for the syntax, I'm not sure what you mean. Why isn't anybody understand it, please? *JustFake* is a property (publicly available) and it produces the faked up array of two strings. I'll be happy to make it clearer but I'm not sure what's wrong... The code compiles and runs but that's not equivalent to being humanly readable, of course. Let me know what can be improved, please.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Thats not a property as shown unless the `=>` is a special syntax I'm not aware of (and not just a typo). I agree, it looks like full code though.

Comment: @Clemens Perhaps we're just calling it different names? What would you call it? A public field? A member variable? It's valid C# syntax according to the docs and compiler, not that it matters, perhaps, since the syntax *get;set;* didn't make much difference...

Comment: @KonradViltersten A public field is very different than a property for binding purposes. As far as it being valid C# syntax, I would question that. The only valid use of `=>` to my knowledge is in a lambda expression. Could you point to the documentation that says its valid?

Comment: It does not even compile. If you replace `=>` by `=` then it's a public field with initializer. Not a property. Read the answer given by @BradleyDotNET. It explains everything.

Comment: @Clemens It does compile. But I forgot to mention that it's 2015 and we're using the new framework, hehe. Darn, I get used to new toys quickly... Bradleys reply is correct and working. But it didn't have to do with the syntax, luckily. :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Do you still want me to link to docs on it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sure, it looks like it changed since the initial C# 6.0 syntax release, so I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Apparently, I got that from a blog. Look for "expression-bodied function members". Also, in case you see something weird like *public String Beep {get;set;} = "booya";*, that's valid too. I love it. But I love most of new stuff in C#.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Just a note, from reading the first blog post I came across, that syntax may still be making a *member* and not a *property*. Its hard to say for sure, so if it works, fine, but be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<String> JustFake = new List<String> { "aaa", "bbb" };
```

Declares a public *field*, which cannot be bound against. You need a *property*:

```
public IEnumerable<String> JustFake { get; set;}

public Presenter()
{
    JustFake = new List<String> { "aaa", "bbb" };
}
```

If you want to set the property after the constructor, you would need to utilize `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and if you want to modify the collection, make sure to use an `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`, as it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

**Update**: You were apparently using a C# 6 expression member, so you may be OK on that front.

**Update 2**: From the exception you reported, it appears that your `DataContext` is either not set, or being set later to `this`. Check and make sure nothing is overriding it.

Comment: Hmm... But I didn't do that. I went *JustFake => ...* so it's supposed to be a property of the class. Or am I mistaken? ALso, I've rewritten it to the syntax suggested by you but still donät get it to work. The combo box is all empty... Suggestions?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Thats not valid syntax from a quick google check, I'd be interested to see a reference as to what you are using to generate that. Regardless, are you getting any `System.Data` exceptions in your output window? Those will point you to any binding errors/typos you may have.

Comment: I'm not getting any exception as far i could see... As for the syntax, I assumed that since it compiles and is defined in the language specification, it should be valid... At any rate, I changed that to *get;set*-syntax for now. No change in behavior, though...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Like I said, I would be interested to see that spec, since it doesn't compile for me. Just to be clear, you are checking the *output* window, correct? These exceptions won't break the program, just generate a debug log.

Comment: Ah, there we go! You're on to something. +1 for persistence! I get this. What does it mean and how do I kill it?! *System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'JustFake' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=JustFake; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='comboBox'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')*

Comment: @KonradViltersten Its as if your `DataContext` isn't actually getting set. In the View constructor, could you try `DataContext = new Presenter()` instead of the XAML syntax?

Comment: Killed it. Some idiot put in *DataContext = this;* in the init method. Total moron did so for static data and then forgot about it. Ignorant... (I'm the only one on **this** project... LOL)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Glad you figured it out! So you know what tipped me off, the exception indicated it was looking for the "JustFake" property on a `MainWindow` not a `Presenter` . Hence, your `DataContext` either not being set, or something overriding it later, as you found.

Comment: I wouldn't stretch as far as to saying that **I did** figure it out. It was more of **you** thingy. But sure. Let's play modest and give the credit. Well, glad - that I am! I'd bounty you if I wouldn't be a cheap rep-junkie and you 25k big.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Well, you noticed the error once I told you where to look, I'll give you the credit :).

Answer (score 0):

Binding to `ItemSource` on an `ItemsControl`, such as a `ListBox`, or a `DataGrid` requires a public property:

```
class Presenter
{
  public List<string> JustFake { get; set; }

  public Presenter() 
  {
     JustFake = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb" };
  }
}
```

To support notifications back to the UI, the collection requires an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, it is often easier to use or derive from a collection class that already implements it. The `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
class Presenter
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> JustFake { get; set; }

  public Presenter() 
  {
     JustFake = new ObservableCollection<string> { "aaa", "bbb" };
  }
}
```

Comment: You actually didn't do an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. Using `ObservableCollection` allows the UI to pick up collection modifications via `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You did pick up on the property requirement, but you might want to include that as the explanation.

Comment: Also, to your edit, **there is no such requirement**. You only have to do that if you want changes to the collection to propagate to the UI. Setting it up in the constructor will work just fine for `List`. Come by the WPF chat room if you want to discuss it.

Comment: I've tried implementing the *INotify...* thingy. No difference there. ALso, I'm not going to need the propagation of changes in the model (static fields, always the same values). Well, almost always.

Comment: I followed the change exactly. Sadly, we're not there yet. I get the same behavior (empty combo box). It's like the binding isn't enabled on the actual property or class...

Comment: I just saw your edit. However, I **am** using a public property in the code sample in the question. Am I not? Am I missing something?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Just checked to verify, and no, it doesn't compile .NET 4.5 VS 2012.

Comment: It compiles on my machine. Are you using a different version of the framework?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Ah, I'm using VS2015 so the new C# is there by default. I so loved the new syntax that I forgot already it was **new**. My bad... Anyway, switching to *get;set;* still reproduces the issue... Suggestions?

Comment: @KonradViltersten That explains it then, as long as its a property that part should be fine.

Comment: It compiles, lol. You're just stuck in 2014, hehehe. Sorry there. I'm on the new framework, for once. Still the issue remains irregardless of the syntax. What else can I be missing?